# css3 background image not loading when api is hosted on a virtual directory?

Tags: html, css

I have my server api(asp.net mvc) exposed in http://localhost:8088/myApp/, here "myApp" is a virtual directory. And from css i am loading a image by background-image property like this,

`.brand { 
    background-image: url('../content/images/logo.png');
}`

now browser is making the request at http://localhost:8088/content/images/logo.png , and server can not serve the image.
What is the **proper request url** for this case?

Comment: If you wrote on CSS file, you should use relative path from your html. 
Assume you put CSS file on CSS folder and have same level with Content folder, your URL should be: 
`content/images/logo.png`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I didn't know about it earlier. If anyone might look for it in the future i am posting my solution. It's the html `base` tag. I just put my base tag,

`<base href="/myApp/">`

on the `head` element on top all other tags then turned my css into

`.brand { 
    background-image: url('content/images/logo.png');
}`

and things working just fine. You can find more about `base` tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 0):

If your .css file is located in your "myApp" folder, then use following code:

```
.brand { 
    background-image: url('content/images/logo.png');
}
```

This code assumes you have a folder "content" and inside "images" folder with your actual images.

Comment: "myApp" isn't a actual directory it's a virtual directory on IIS server, "http://localhost:8088/myApp/" is the root directory, request on this url IIS server will serve from my exposed api.